# Is there Spring Social for Youtube?

Tags: youtube-api, spring-social

Is there any support for youtube in Spring Social?
I have searched and have not found any.
If not in Spring Social, can someone give me some pointers to explore youtube apis (to load the history and such)?

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no support from spring social for youtube but the way u can achieve the functionalities are from Youtube data api,livestreaming api from google are helpful